# what's the difference between cleaned_data and normal data? - django

Tags: python, django, forms, post

as mentioned in title...what's the difference?
I have seen people keep on saying use `cleaned_data` and in videos people still say so but only says it cleans the data but when I use print

```
    print form.cleaned_data.get('title')
    print request.POST.get('title')
```

I don't see any difference though.  At first I thought it's those character escape and so but tested and doesn't seem so.

which is actually a preferred way since there doesn't seem to have differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not trust on request data as it is raw data which are not validated. You should never use data from `request` and store it to your database.

It so important that you store only valid data in database for smooth functioning of application. Django forms `cleaned_data` ensure you that validation rules defines for that form are satisfied or not. `form.is_valid()` check all your validations against `request.POST` data and generate dictionary containing valid data which is `form.cleaned_data`.
So data retrieved from `forms.cleaned_data` attribute are go through form validation. It's not only validation but also converted data to relevant python type too.

You can also refer this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) to know how Django form perform validation.

Comment: by relevant python type, it means something such as whatever field we set in the model?

Comment: Yes. Form's `<field>_clean` method ensure that it returns python object, not the original string submitted in the form.

Comment: sorry I just got one more question, somehow if we aren't using form based on django so cannot use `form.is_valid()` would something like this work? `request.data.cleaned_data.get('email')`

Comment: No. You must be aware that cleaned_data is attribute of `django.forms.Form` you can not write `request.data.cleaned_data` it will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: is there another way to clean the data without using the `cleaned_data` attribute?

Comment: You can write custom Validator class to perform validation on request.

Comment: that sounds more like writing the validation from scratch right?

Comment: Yes. Rather than discussing each and every points here I advise you to read out something related on bogs/sites try to implement and than raise an issue if you found any difficulty.